# strange "w."-subdomain appearing in Google search results

Tags: google-search, sitemap

The name of my site is https://www.example.com, but during a routine check, I've found that along with the usual search results, Google also brought up 1 weird "subdomain" page (only a single page) in the results, with an URL like
https://w.example.com/page.htm when I only searched on the domain entered without "www." (like "searchterm site:example.com").

I found no reference to page.htm in all source code of the page, no reference to w.example.com in any of the settings, the Google sitemap, the Google search console, or the robots.txt file.

Does anyone have an idea where this strange, "truncated" URL (that is listed along with the results for my site!) may come from? I need to get rid of it.

Comment: Did you Google the  https://w.example.com/page.htm url without the 'site:' command? Perhaps is it reffered on another website? Where does the link lead? On your server?

Comment: when I enter this URL in Google search, it is displayed as a result. However, when I click it, it opens "w.example.com" (which puzzles me!) and says "page.htm can not be found on this server" (which is correct, this page doesn't exist on the example.com server). Looks like a domain misconfiguration to me? I'm managing my server with Plesk and would be surprised if it produces such a weird effect (because page.htm is actually from another domain!).

Comment: Do you have the `w.` subdomain added in DNS specifically, or is there a wildcard that points all subdomains to your server?     How are you handling weird subdomains on the server?  Are you redirecting them to `www.`?

Comment: No, there is no definition of a w. subdomain anywhere in the plesk DNS setup interface. The domains are set up to forward to https:// and www. automatically via 301, yes.